# Google monitoring selected metric is invalid?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I literally am clicking a metric that works for the last 2 months from our dashboard and it shows a graph WITH data like so (you can see in red, it is saying invalid metric).

[image]

So, metrics HALF works.  The real issue is I can no longer see ANY of our company metrics that I don't already have predefined in the dashboard.  Is there a work around for this odd issue?

EDIT: Even more frustrating is how the logs find the metric just fine...

[image]
thanks,
Dean

Comment: The red metric is an indication of missing data. It looks like something is wrong with the underlying data for your project. 

You can open a ticket with [Google Cloud support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) and provide your project ID information so we can investigate further(For free users this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/)) or report it as a defect using Google Cloud Platform's [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports).

Comment: I see this all the time too, except with brand new log-based metrics, which also have no problem finding their log entries (ie they appear completely valid). However, if I wait 10 or 15 minutes, the metric will then become available for use in the metric explorer, or an alerting policy.