# Google Monitoring another bug? and how to ever report these?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

Well, there is definitely a conflict in this picture.  I filter to cluster_name="staging-incomingdb" and then if you look at the cluster_name column, it is showing "staging-scrapers".  Has anyone else seen this?

[image]

Has anyone else seen this or more importantly, do they have a workaround?

Yesterday it was this post [Google monitoring selected metric is invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604896/google-monitoring-selected-metric-is-invalid) and today this one.

We are considering just getting off the entire google platform since metrics is the key to monitoring production and google's doesn't seem to work and is very costly.  If anyone has something more stable working in google, PLEASE, let us know!!!  This is getting really bad for monitoring our production systems.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: From looking at the screenshot provided, it could be that you are using the wrong resource type. The resource type you are currently using is "GKE Container". This is an older version of a resource type. I suggest trying to use "Kubernetes Container" as the resource type as per the attached documentation [1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes#kubernetes-kubernetes.

Comment: @Jason  I found out google had a outage of returning http 500's and they don't have cloud monitoring on their status page.  I found out on a response to a ticket.  All is working again thank god!!

Comment: `Operations` is the row for Monitoring/Logging/Tracing at https://status.cloud.google.com/